# How do I create a function that takes Any type and outputs the JSON stringified version of it?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm a bit bugged by using the following code over and over to shape my data into JSON and was hoping there is a native reusable function to achieve the same thing where I can pass in anything, it will check if it is Encodable and either output nil or the String:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
            
guard let jsonDateData = try? encoder.encode(dateOfApproval) else {return}
guard let myDateString = String(data: jsonDateData, encoding: .utf8) else {return}
```

The core of the issue seems to be that I can't check if the Any object that is sent in is Encodable, leaving me to check the specific type (as I have below):

```
func shapeData(dataToShape: Any)-> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    
    if let hi = dataToShape as? String { // I'd prfer to be able to check if it's encodable here instead of a specific type
        guard let jsonDateData = try? encoder.encode(hi) else {return nil}
        guard let myDateString = String(data: jsonDateData, encoding: .utf8) else {return nil}
        return myDateString
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I tried `if dataToShape is Encodable` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function generic. This way your `dataToShape` parameter will be of some generic type which you can constrain to `Encodable`:

```
func shapeData<T>(dataToShape: T) -> String? where T: Encodable {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    
    guard let jsonDateData = try? encoder.encode(dataToShape) else {return nil}
    guard let myDateString = String(data: jsonDateData, encoding: .utf8) else {return nil}
    return myDateString
}
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a dream, I'll accept when Stackoverflow lets me. I've probably gotten too far without generics knowledge...

Comment: @mpc75 I recommend the Swift documentation of [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html). It's really good.